# Why 8th decimal digit is recognized in 16_711_711f == 16_711_712f, shouldn't float have only 7 decimal digits precision?

Tags: java, floating-point

float is 32 bits. Exponent is 8 bits. Hence significand is 32-8 = 24 bits (minus sign bit plus one implicit bit).

If 24 bits are used to store significant (binary) digits, then only log10(2^24)=7 decimal significant digits can be stored - regardless whether those are decimal digits (after dot) or digits of integer part.

Why in example below 8th decimal digit is recognized? Where is a mistake in my reasoning?

```
float f1 = 16_711_711;
float f2 = 16_711_712;

System.out.println(f1 == f2); // false
```

Comment: `2^24 = 16*(2^10)^2 = 16*(10^6+2*24*10^3+24^2) > 16,768,000` so that your two numbers are still inside the segment of consecutive integers that are representable as `float`.

Comment: "then only log10(2^24)=7 decimal significant digits can be stored" --> Not quite.  The mapping of 24 binary significance to decimal significance wobbles from 6 to 9 digits for `float`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

log10(2^24) is roughly 7.22.

You're seeing the .22 here.

It can hold 7 digits perfectly and will be able to store some information about the eight, but can't hold it all. You happen to have found an example where there's enough information to distinguish the two.

Comment: I'm afraid that any mumber smaller than 2^24 = 16_777_216 would have no problems, which does not explain that 0.22 trick. Seems EVERY number having more than 7 digits under 16_777_216 is exact...

Comment: It does. It can represent *some* numbers with 8 digits correctly, but not all of them. That's what a non-integer number of digits means in this case. Keep in mind that the log10() is just a clutch for us humans who think in base-10. In fact it can represent *exactly* 24 digits, but those are binary digits.

Comment: Sorry, I finally got it!  16_777_217 also has 8 digits, but cannot be represented exactly!

Comment: @caasdas: exactly. At some point, it can only represent numbers that are a multiple of two, then, at another, higher point, it can only represent multiples of 8, then 16, 32, etc. exactly. So some integer values with more than 7 **significant** digits can be represented exactly, but not all. The larger they are, the more values fall inbetween that can't be represented.